# A conceptual doubt concerning linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y'+ay=b(x)$, where $a$ is a constant and $b$ a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ such that $|b(x)|\leq k$. Find the solution satisfying $y(0)=0$.

I know the solution has the form

$$y=e^{-ax} \int^x_{x_0} e^{at} b(t)dt + Ce^{-ax}$$

with $x_0\in[0,\infty)$. Hence,

$$0= \int^0_{x_0} e^{at} b(t)dt + C \iff \\ C = -\int^0_{x_0} e^{at} b(t)dt = \int^{x_0}_{0} e^{at} b(t)dt$$

Now, the texbook says the solution is $y=e^{-ax} \int^x_{0} e^{at} b(t)dt$.

But I don't understand why $C=0$ or $x_0 = 0$. We could choose $x_0=0$, but we could also choose $x_0=100^{100}$. Besides, why do we need to assume that $b$ is continuous **and bounded**? Boundedness is overkill as an integrability condition.

Comment: $x_0$ must be less than or equal than zero. Otherwise, the fundamental theorem of calculus yields a minus sign for $0 < x < x_0$. One has to choose $x_0 = 0$ from the domain where $b(t)$ is defined. This yields $C = 0$. Finally, you're right bounded is an overkill. Probably the author does not want to scare the reader with a weaker condition.

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas But I did account for that, didn't I? 

$C = -\int^0_{x_0} e^{at} b(t)dt = \int^{x_0}_{0} e^{at} b(t)dt$

Comment: No, in that case the derivative of $\int_{x_0}^{x}e^{at}b(t)dt$ is $e^{at}b(t)$ but with a minus sign (in the interval $0 < x < x_0$). So that $y$ is not a solution to the differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us insert initial condition $x=0,y(0) = 0$ into equation, we then get:

$$y'(0)+\underset{0}{\underbrace{ay(0)}}=b(0)$$

$y'(0)=b(0)$ because of initial condition.

Can you see what this forces $C$ and $x_0$ to be?

**Hint**: use differentiation together with [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) on the general solution with $C$ and $x_0$.

Comment: Any explanation..?